# I would like to execute a line of code if a meta tag contains specific text using JQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I created some code that is suppose to execute if the meta tag's attribute (content) equals or contains "Soda" but for some reason it isn't working. I'm not sure if my code is reading my variable or if there is something else wrong.

```
var metaSection = $("meta[property='article:section']").attr("content");

if (metaSection == 'Soda') {
    alert ('The is a Soda Page!');
}
```

My Meta tag with the HTML is:

```
<meta property="article:section" content="Soda" />
```

Comment: If the alert fires, then your code is working!

Comment: "equals or contains" <= actually, you are just checking if it equals, not if it contains.

Comment: @SleekGeek That's the thing. My alert isn't firing

Comment: To make sure, the script runs after document is fully loaded, wrap your code with the _$().ready()_ function: `$(document).ready(function(){  /*your code here*/  });`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any markup, but as you can see in this executable snippet, it definitely works with the code you provided:

```js
var metaSection = $("meta[property='article:section']").attr("content");

if (metaSection == 'Soda') {
    alert ('The is a Soda Page!');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta property="article:section" content="Soda" />
```

Comment: Good catch I'll update my code to show a bit of markup.

Comment: When you execute my snippet, it doesn't work? For me it does, I get the alert.

Comment: Yeah, it's not working. I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: I checked Firefox and Chrome, as soon as I click the "run code snippet" button, the alert pops up. Which browser are you using?